# Django rest framework, use none in model's field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a Django rest framework API, In one of the models, there is a field for GeoLocation's elevation, which defaults its value to None.

The reason for that is that it can be passed in by the user or if left empty, obtained by a call to google's elevation API.

So, I'm trying to use the create function in the serializer to define its value but I'm getting a key error:

```py
#app/models.py

  elevation = models.FloatField(name="Elevation",
                                  max_length=255,
                                  help_text="If known, Add location's sea level height. If not, Leave Empty.",
                                  null=False,
                                  default=None)
```

```py
#app/serializers.py
from rest_framework.serializers import HyperlinkedModelSerializer

from Project_Level.utils import get_elevation
from .models import KnownLocation

class KnownLocationSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if validated_data["Elevation"] is None:  # Using if not validated_data["Elevation"] results the same.
            validated_data["Elevation"] = get_elevation(validated_data["Latitude"], validated_data["Longitude"])

    class Meta:
        model = KnownLocation
        fields = ('id', 'Name', 'Area', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Elevation')
```

Error:

```
KeyError at /knownlocations/
'Elevation'
Exception Location: KnownLocation/serializers.py in create, line 9
```

Answer (score 0):

> elevation = models.FloatField...
>
> fields = ('id', 'Name', 'Area', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Elevation')

field names are case-sensitive, elevation != Elevation. Try using lowercase only.